# YQL Console working inconsistently

Tags: yql, finance

I'm trying to make a finance app that, for now, pulls stock quotes. My problem is detailed below:

1. On the developer's console (http://developer.yahoo.com/yql/console/), I will click "show community tables" on the right under "Data Tables"
2. I type in 'select * from yahoo.finance.quotes where symbol="YHOO" ' for my YQL statement
3. I click the JSON radio button
4. I erase "cbfunc" and uncheck the Diagnostic checkbox
5. I click "test" and what I want to appear appears: { "query": { "count": 1, "created": "2012-12-03T09:11:12Z", "lang": "en-US", "results": { "quote": { "symbol": "YHOO", "Ask": null, ... etc
6. Under "The Rest Query", [it gives me a link that I can use to access what is displayed](http://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?q=select%20%2a%20from%20yahoo.finance.quotes%20where%20symbol=%22YHOO%22&format=json&env=store://datatables.org/alltableswithkeys). That link, which my program calls, does not work. It shows `{"query":{"count":0,"created":"2012-12-03T09:12:44Z","lang":"en-US","results":null}}` instead, but not always - sometimes it works and sometimes it doesn't.

Does anyone know why?

Answer (score 1):

It's possible that you are running into a rate-limit problem.

I would enable the Diagnostics option - that will include in the output details of the calls made by YQL and whether any returned data. Here's a YQL Console link to your sample query, with diagnostics enabled:

[`select * from yahoo.finance.quotes where symbol="YHOO"`](http://developer.yahoo.com/yql/console/?q=select%20%2a%20from%20yahoo.finance.quotes%20where%20symbol%3D%22YHOO%22&env=store%3A%2F%2Fdatatables.org%2Falltableswithkeys)